# AFNetworking 2.0 API For Multi-part form upload

Tags: ios, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

What is the AFNetworking 2.0 method for uploading a multipart form i.e.  With `AFHTTPSessionManager` or `AFHTTPRequestOperationManager`

Here is an example of some AFNetworking < 2.0 code:

```
[[ASAPIClient sharedClient] enqueueHTTPRequestOperation:[[ASAPIClient sharedClient] HTTPRequestOperationWithRequest:[[ASAPIClient sharedClient] multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" path:@"/some/url" parameters:params constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
        if(_selectedPhoto.image)
        {
            NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation([_selectedPhoto image], 0.5);

            [formData appendPartWithFileData:imageData name:@"avatar" fileName:@"avatar.jpg" mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];
        }
    }] success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

        if([[responseObject objectForKey:@"result"]isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]] )
        {

        }

    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

    }]];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ASAPIManager` is a subclass of `AFHTTPRequestOperationManager`

```
[[ASAPIManager sharedManager] POST:@"/some/url" parameters:params constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
        if(_profileImageView.image){
            [formData appendPartWithFileData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(_profileImageView.image, 0.5) name:@"avatar" fileName:@"avatar.jpg" mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];
        }
    } success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

    }];
```

Comment: have "name" and "filename" to be as original? and I guess ASAPIManager is a subclass of AFHTTPRequestOperationManager ?

Comment: @raistlin name and filename can be whatever you please, but it is prob good practice to make sure that the extension of the filename matches the mimeType