# how to upload image byte stream data to server in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to upload one image to server using http post method.
the requirement is like in the body data should be attached as byte stream.

My code

```
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url-string]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
[request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];
NSMutableData *postbody = [NSMutableData data];

[postbody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[postbody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data;       name=\"%@\"; filename=\"%@\"\r\n",@"images.jpg",@"images"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[postbody appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[postbody appendData:[NSData dataWithData:data]];

[postbody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[request setHTTPBody:postbody];
```

but i am getting **404 error** in status code.

is byte stream is same as `NSData` ?

if not then how to send byte stream data to server using `NSURLConnection` ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://zcentric.com/2008/08/29/post-a-uiimage-to-the-web/

Comment: 404 means Bad request or something you are trying is not found on server, so check url you are sending to.

Comment: Please check the "url-string", The error might be occuring due to the wrong url, as the code for multipart form data request is right.

Comment: Try to encode the image in base64 first. That should give you the correct byte stream array.

Comment: the requirement is to send byte stream image data in the body of http post method. can any one tell me how to send byte stream data with NSUrlconnection. currently i am sending it as nsdata in the body,i am expecting that might be the reason.please answer me know how to send byte stream data.

Comment: AFNetworking as a method to send multipart request:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19443241/afnetworking-2-0-api-for-multi-part-form-upload  if that doesn't work you might need to send your stream in chunks which is more complicated.